# What is wrong with my log4net wrapper?

Tags: .net-core, log4net

I've made a wrapper for log4net but it has a very strage behavior. I'm using NET Core 2 and in my test class the logger works BUT only if I add another call to the logger from inside the logger (see comment in my code). And if I try that code in a console app again it will not log.

Here is my code:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Logger.configuration.xml", Watch = true)]
namespace MyCreatives.Common.Logging
{
    public static class LoggerAdapter
    {
        public static ILogger Logger = new Logger();

    }
}

internal class Logger : ILogger
    {
        private static ILog _log => LogManager.GetLogger(getClassType());

        #region Log methods

        public void LogDebug(string message, Exception e = null)
        {
            _log.Debug(message, e);
        }

        public void LogError(string message, Exception e = null)
        {
            LoggerAdapter.Logger.LogInfo("info");//if I remove this it won't log
            _log.Error(message, e);
        }

        public void LogFatal(string message, Exception e = null)
        {
            _log.Fatal(message, e);
        }

        public void LogInfo(string message, Exception e = null)
        {
            _log.Info(message, e);
        }

        public void LogWarning(string message, Exception e = null)
        {
            _log.Warn(message, e);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

And config file:

```
<log4net>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>

  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="example.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

</log4net>
```

What is the problem here and how can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is in this code:

```
public static class LoggerAdapter
{
    public static ILogger Logger = new Logger();

}
```

Your logger should be initalized with the log manager:

```
LogManager.GetLogger(........);
```